# How to program a TRIGGER on SQLite Manager

Tags: sqlite, firefox, triggers

I want to make a trigger that when in my table called 'tickets' a column called 'summary' was a specificity phrase it will update a column (in the same table) called 'id' to a number I want

Is this syntax I have but it doesn't work

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS paulo  AFTER  INSERT ON tickets  
FOR EACH ROW  BEGIN 
if (summary) ='quero mudar o ano'
 update id  set id='2013000000';
END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

This syntax error is because SQLite does not allow the IF clause in the triggers. Here is the specification **http://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html**

```
  CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS paulo  AFTER  INSERT ON tickets  
FOR EACH ROW  
WHEN (summary) ='quero mudar o ano'
BEGIN 
 update id  set id='2013000000';

END;
```

O Problema é que se você quiser comparar um outro valor será preciso criar uma outra trigger, ja que não é possivel usar o ELSE IF. :(